# How to iterate on the field of an enum in Java?

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

I have this Java **enum**:

```
public enum ConnectionParameter {
    state,
    host,
    port,
    secure,
    username,
    password
}
```

that contains the fields of an XML file on which I have to work using XPATH (but this is not important at this time)

I have to iterate on all this enum fields to do an operation for each one.

How can I do it?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: `ConnectionParameter.values()` returns an array of all the `enum` values declared in that `enum`.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Have you tried using its autocomplete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for(ConnectionParameter item : ConnectionParameter.values())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ConnectionParameter.values()` that returns you an array with all the constants defined in the enum. Example:

```
for (ConnectionParameter c :ConnectionParameter.values()) {
   System.out.println(c.printableName());
}
```

More info:

- [Enums in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `values()` method like this:

```
for (ConnectionParameter connectionParameter : ConnectionParameter.values()) {
   // do somethign with `connectionParameter` here
}
```

Every `enum` has this `values()` method.